# Where can I get the SharePoint 2016 RTM SDK/templates for building server-side code in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2015

I've been Googling, but not finding anything on it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the bottom part of this blog post: [Latest Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/11/23/latest-microsoft-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2015/). It says the tools are for Beta 2 but they do work with the RC or RTM version. These are the latest tools as far as I know.

I cover this and more in [What's New for Developers in SharePoint 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuNzniUKNhc).

Edit: From the article and video:

1. Install the [Latest Office Tools (aka.ms/GetLatestOfficeDevTools)](http://aka.ms/GetLatestOfficeDevTools)
2. Install the [Office Tools Preview for Visual Studio 2015](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49972)

Comment: Those tools only include SharePoint 2013 and 2010 project items; if I attempt to create an empty SharePoint 2016 project in VS 2015, I get an error that SharePoint '15' isn't installed.

Comment: Did you install both sets of tools (i.e. the latest official tools and the preview tools)?

Comment: I finally was able to download and install the two needed installation packages. I updated your answer with the TL;DR/TL;DW info for folks who come here for brevity. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above did'nt work - This article helped me 
http://asish.com.au/sharepoint-2016-project-templates-missing-visual-studio-2015/

HTH